# Invalid Template Deployment

Tags: powershell, azure, templates

Up until a couple of weeks ago, I could deploy new Azure VM's based on a template we created. Now I'm getting the following error messages

```
   VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Replacing resource group ..." on target "".
VERBOSE: 12:45:43 PM - Created resource group 'Core613a-RGP' in location 'eastus2'
Creating storage account core613astr ...
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Creating Deployment" on target "Core613a-RGP".
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 12:51:18 PM - Error: Code=InvalidTemplateDeployment; Message=The template
deployment 'azuredeploy-Core613a-0221-1851' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is
'ce71bcac-7a7b-40a8-b920-06f5322984fe'. See inner errors for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage
details.
At C:\Code\Azure\Core613a\Deploy-Core613a.ps1:191 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $TemplateFil ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep
   loymentCmdlet


New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : The deployment validation failed
At C:\Code\Azure\Core613a\Deploy-Core613a.ps1:191 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $TemplateFil ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep
   loymentCmdlet

Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress : The Resource 'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/Core613a-PIP' under resource group
'Core613a-RGP' was not found.
StatusCode: 404
ReasonPhrase: Not Found
OperationID : 'c272c46b-edef-4846-a460-7529d372a400'
At C:\Code\Azure\Core613a\Deploy-Core613a.ps1:202 char:13
+ ...  $vmPubIP = Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGr ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress], NetworkCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.GetAzurePublicIpAddressCommand



The property 'DnsSettings' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
At C:\Code\Azure\Core613a\Deploy-Core613a.ps1:205 char:41
+ ... te-Host "Your FQDN is:            $($vmPubIP.DnsSettings.Fqdn)" -fore ...
+                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict

Your FQDN is:
The property 'IpAddress' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
At C:\Code\Azure\Core613a\Deploy-Core613a.ps1:206 char:41
+     Write-Host "Your IP address is:      $($vmPubIP.IpAddress)" -fore ...
+                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict
```

My assumption would be something changed in the validation procedure, but I'm not sure how to go about tracking down the issue.

The following is used to kick-off the entire process
[Deployment Script](https://gist.github.com/jwstl/9d081cd7ea276cc14700dc3069a9e80c)

This is the deployment template
[Deployment Template](https://gist.github.com/jwstl/d3b4cc62f1648346024df59d4853f993)

Parameters template
[Parameters Template](https://gist.github.com/jwstl/a4ba1839a7bcb018777cfe1348511039)

Comment: `Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` and look for errors

Comment: also, your deployment process looks overly complicated for a simple vm deployment

Comment: @Jason I execute your cmdlet step by step, I could create Public IP. If possible, I suggest you test step by step and find the error reason.